# In Terraform, how do you specify an API Gateway endpoint with a variable in the request path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

In AWS API Gateway, I have a endpoint defined as `/users/{userId}/someAction`, and I'm trying to recreate this with terraform

I would start having some sort of linked gateway_resource chain like so...

```hcl
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Users" {
  rest_api_id = "${var.rest_api_id}" 
  parent_id = "${var.parent_id}" 
  path_part = "users"
}

//{userId} here?

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "SomeAction" {
  rest_api_id = "${var.rest_api_id}" 
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.UserIdReference.id}"
  path_part = "someAction"
}
```

In which I then define the `aws_api_gateway_method` and everything else.

How do I define this endpoint in terraform?  The terraform documentation and examples don't cover this use case.

Comment: adding to the answer, you can change the parent_id to point to the `aws_api_gateway_resource` that has the dynamic param.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to define a [resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/api_gateway_resource.html) whose `path_part` is the parameter you want to use:

```hcl
// List
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "accounts" {
    rest_api_id = var.gateway_id
    parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.finance.id
    path_part   = "accounts"
}

// Unit
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "account" {
  rest_api_id = var.gateway_id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.accounts.id
  path_part   = "{accountId}"
}
```

Then you create the [method](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_method.html) and **enable** the path parameter:

```hcl
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get-account" {
  rest_api_id   = var.gateway_id
  resource_id   = var.resource_id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.accountId" = true
  }
}
```

And finally you can successfully create the mapping within the [integration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html):

```hcl
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "get-account-integration" {
    rest_api_id             = var.gateway_id
    resource_id             = var.resource_id
    http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.get-account.http_method
    type                    = "HTTP"
    integration_http_method = "GET"
    uri                     = "/integration/accounts/{id}"
    passthrough_behavior    = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"

    request_parameters = {
        "integration.request.path.id" = "method.request.path.accountId"
    }
}
```

The method needs to be there - and with the parameter enabled - in order for the integration mapping to work.

Comment: Isn't this only for the `users/{userId}` portion of the OP's question?

Currently facing same issue as the original question: managed to get `resource/{resourceId}` working, but not `resource/{resourceId}/someAction`.

Tried creating another resource under the `{pathId}` resource, with it's own method and integration, but I get a "Missing Authentication Token" error – which leads me to suspect it didn't really create anything.

Comment: Where in the docs did you find this solution? Was it just diving into AWS docs?

Comment: Equals operator `=` required for the assignment to `request_parameters`in method and integration, as per docs e.g. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration.html#request_parameters

Comment: I see that `aws_api_gateway_resource.account` is defined, but it doesn't appear to be referenced anywhere. Is this an oversight? I would have expected it might be used in `aws_api_gateway_method.get-account`. Perhaps in its `resource_id` field?