# Attach multiple HTTP methods on API Gateway resource using AWS_PROXY integration

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

How can I attach the PUT and DELETE method on an API Gateway resource using AWS_PROXY integration?

The PUT method is getting overridden by the DELETE method in lambda triggers.

Is there a way to have both the methods? [image]

```
/subs
OPTIONS
PUT
DELETE
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method#example-usage) in terraform registry documentation, define multiple `aws_api_gateway_method` resources for the same `aws_api_gateway_resource` resource:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name        = "MyAPI"
  description = "This is my API"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "subs" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "subs"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "methods" {
  for_each      = toset(["OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"])

  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.subs.id
  http_method   = each.key
  authorization = "CUSTOM"
}
```

Comment: The original question was using a Proxy - this does not actually set up a proxy, but individual methods for each one.

its a subtle difference, but there are advantages to using a proxy - the lack of need for each path_part to be defined for instance (as the path is included in the event sent to the lambda attached to the proxy)

Comment: I undertood how to implement multiple methods. If the original question is only about creating a proxy and and api gateway, it is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105470/14105382, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a proxy method, it sends a ton of information to the lambda. Change the proxy method to "ANY" and then in your lambda, check against the event.HttpMethod - and only process based on the ones you want to allow, returning an error message otherwise.

If you dont want to do this, then you need to stop using a proxy method and instead set up an actual resource + each method. THey can connect to the same lambda or different ones, but you can't use proxy to define just two types - its 1 or all.